# Following a link after a jquery event

Tags: jquery, animation, hyperlink

I have a navigation bar I am animating once the item has been clicked. I would like to follow the link after the navigation is complete.

HTML:

```
<div id="project-nav">
    <ul> 
        <a href="" >
            <li class="project-3">1
                <ul> 
                    <li>WAIKANAE BEACH HOUSE</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </a>

        <a href="">
            <li class="project-4">2
                <ul> 
                    <li>WAITAHEKE WETLAND HOME</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </a>

        <a href="">
            <li class="project-1">3
                <ul> 
                    <li>WAIKANAE BEACH HOUSE</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </a>
```

Script:

```
$("#project-nav a").click(function(ev) 
{
    ev.preventDefault();

    var $self=$(this);

    $(".project-1").animate( {"top": "+=-500px"}, 1200, function() { showComplete() } );
    $(".project-2").animate( {"top": "+=-500px"}, 1400, function() { showComplete() } );
    $(".project-3").animate( {"top": "+=-500px"}, 1000, function() { showComplete() } );
    $(".project-4").animate( {"top": "+=-500px"}, 1000, function() { showComplete() } );
    $(".project-5").animate( {"top": "+=-500px"}, 1000, function() { showComplete() } );
});

function showComplete()
{
    document.location = $self.attr('href');
}
```

Here is what I have so far, the animation works but it doesn't follow the link.

Comment: just a little side note `window.location` is more reliable than `document.location`. in most cases it won't make a difference but if you have e.g. `<img name="location">` in your html code, `document.location` points to the `img` but `window.location` still points to the location object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is `$self` is declared outside of the scope of `showComplete`.

Try this instead:

```
$("#project-nav a").click(function(ev) {

    ev.preventDefault();
    var $self=$(this);

    $(".project-1").animate( {"top": "+=-500px"}, 1200, showComplete);
    $(".project-2").animate( {"top": "+=-500px"}, 1400, showComplete);
    $(".project-3").animate( {"top": "+=-500px"}, 1000, showComplete);
    $(".project-4").animate( {"top": "+=-500px"}, 1000, showComplete);
    $(".project-5").animate( {"top": "+=-500px"}, 1000, showComplete);

    function showComplete(){
        window.location = $self.attr('href');
    }
});
```

What I did was move `showComplete` inside the event handler.

Answer (score 0):

$self is out of scope in `showComplete()`.

You should pass a parameter instead.

**Exemple**

```
$(".project-5").animate( {"top": "+=-500px"}, 1000, function() { showComplete($self.attr("href")) } );

function showComplete(pUrl){
    document.location = pUrl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is `$self` is undefined. It only exists in the function it was created.

You need to do: showComplete($self);

Then in the function creation:

```
showComplete(el){
    document.location = el.attr('href');
}
```